# Fighing with TS2322 error about generic value asignment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to create some higher-order react components that will have some default values for components "named". This is the simple implementation that I'd like to work (this is just an example to showcase the problem):

```
type SomeProps = {
  a: string
}
type Variants = 'variantA' | 'variantB'
const somePredefinedValues: Record<Variants, SomeProps> = {
  variantA: { a: 'a' },
  variantB: { a: 'b' },
}

export const withVariants = <Props extends SomeProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<Props>) => {
  return ({ variant, ...props }: Props & { variant?: Variants }) => {
    if (!variant) {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
    return <Component {...somePredefinedValues[variant]} {...props} />
  }
}
```

This obvoiuslty result with TS2322 error saying that

```
Type 'Omit<Props & { variant?: Variants | undefined; }, "variant">' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Omit<Props & { variant?: Variants | undefined; }, "variant">' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
    'Omit<Props & { variant?: Variants | undefined; }, "variant">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Props', but 'Props' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SomeProps'.
```

I tried many ways to get around this and fix the issue, like (a bit ugly IMO but should be correct):

```
type SomeProps = {
  a: string
}
type Variants = 'variantA' | 'variantB'
const somePredefinedValues: Record<Variants, SomeProps> = {
  variantA: { a: 'a' },
  variantB: { a: 'b' },
}

export const withVariants = <Props,>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<Omit<Props, keyof SomeProps>, 'variant'> & SomeProps>
) => {
  return ({
    variant,
    ...props
  }: Omit<Omit<Props, keyof SomeProps>, 'variant'> & SomeProps & { variant?: Variants }) => {
    const standardProps: Omit<Omit<Props, keyof SomeProps>, 'variant'> & SomeProps = props //here is the issue
    if (!variant) {
      return <Component {...standardProps} />
    }
    return <Component {...somePredefinedValues[variant]} {...standardProps} />
  }
}
```

Which resulted in:

```
Type 'Omit<Omit<Omit<Props, "a">, "variant"> & SomeProps & { variant?: Variants | undefined; }, "variant">' is not assignable to type 'Omit<Omit<Props, "a">, "variant"> & SomeProps'.
  Type 'Omit<Omit<Omit<Props, "a">, "variant"> & SomeProps & { variant?: Variants | undefined; }, "variant">' is not assignable to type 'Omit<Omit<Props, "a">, "variant">'.
    Type 'Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
      Type 'Exclude<keyof Props, "a">' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
        Type 'keyof Props' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
          Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
            Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
              Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | Exclude<Exclude<Exclude<keyof Props, "a">, "variant">, "variant">'.
```

Is there any way to achieve desired behaviour in TS?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by `Omit` (applied implicitly in the first example by TS when destructuring with rest operator) losing the overall type information, as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36981).

Just removing the destructuring seems to do the trick.

```
type SomeProps = {
  a: string
}
type Variants = 'variantA' | 'variantB'
const somePredefinedValues: Record<Variants, SomeProps> = {
  variantA: { a: 'a' },
  variantB: { a: 'b' },
}

export const withVariants = <Props extends SomeProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<Props>) => {
  return (props: Props & { variant?: Variants }) => {
    if (!props.variant) {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
    return <Component {...somePredefinedValues[props.variant]} {...props} />
  }
}
```

Comment: there are two problems with such an approach:
- first is that it somehow silences TS2322 error  without solving it... the thing is that this code works and it should not:
```
const Test = ({ a }: { a: 'test' }) => <div>{a}</div>
const TestWithVariant = withVariants(Test)
<Test variant='variantA' /> // a have value 'a' and Test component only accepts 'test'
```
- the second problem is that variant prop is passed to children (but this may be solvable somehow)